# C# Reading special characters from text file using OleDbConnection

Tags: c#, oledb, oledbconnection

Problem reading .dbf file using OleDbConnection. How to set up the encoding correctly?

My Code:

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + inpath + ";Extended Properties=dBASE IV;Persist Security Info=False;");
```

I tried like this but got an error:

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + inpath + ";Extended Properties=dBASE IV;Persist Security Info=False;CharacterSet=WIN1251;");
```

import.txt

```
OEEAOOAI_A?EEIAOE
```

Comment: Are you sure your data is encoded as WIN1251?  Have you tried UTF8?

Comment: I tried with UTF8. Here the problem is that I added that encoding parameter incorrectly, but in the examples it seems to be added in this way.